# plotting a cumulative ribbon in ggplot R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to create a bar plot with a shaded ribbon showing the cumulative value:

```
require(ggplot2)
plot_data = data.frame(period=factor(c("t_1", "t_5_to_t_2", "t_8_to_t_2", "t_11_to_t_2", "t_14_to_t_2"), levels=c("t_1", "t_5_to_t_2", "t_8_to_t_2", "t_11_to_t_2", "t_14_to_t_2")), vals = 1:5, ribbon_vals = cumsum(1:5))
ggplot(data=plot_data, aes(x=period, y=vals)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", colour=c("#6495ED", "#2E8B57", "#2E8B57", "#2E8B57", "#2E8B57")) + 
scale_x_discrete(labels = c('t_1' = expression(t-1), 't_5_to_t_2' = expression(t-5 %->% t-2), 't_8_to_t_2' = expression(t-8 %->% t-2), 't_11_to_t_2' = expression(t-11 %->% t-2), 't_14_to_t_2' = expression(t-14 %->% t-2))) +
geom_ribbon(aes(x=1:5, y=ribbon_vals))
```

This does not seem to work. What is the correct way to use `geom_ribbon`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `geom_ribbon()` you should provide `ymin` and `ymax` values. `ymin` in this case is 0 and `ymax` is `ribbon_vals`. `geom_ribbon()` line should be placed before `geom_bar()`. Used `fill=` instead of `color=` in `geom_bar()` to change color of whole bar (not just border).

```
ggplot(data=plot_data, aes(x=period, y=vals)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('t_1' = expression(t-1), 't_5_to_t_2' = expression(t-5 %->% t-2), 't_8_to_t_2' = expression(t-8 %->% t-2), 't_11_to_t_2' = expression(t-11 %->% t-2), 't_14_to_t_2' = expression(t-14 %->% t-2))) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=1:5, ymin=0,ymax=ribbon_vals))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",fill=c("#6495ED", "#2E8B57", "#2E8B57", "#2E8B57", "#2E8B57"))
```

[image]

Comment: how does it know what the shape should be and how to connect the ribbons? this is fascinating!